# Typescript with Activex

Tags: typescript, activex

how can i create ActiveX using typescript? as there is no support for CreateObject

```
 var objElement = document.createElement('object');
        objElement.classid = 'clsid:2F3BC10B-45B6-472D-859C-200197E7D9C7';
        objElement.id = objectId;
        objElement.data = 'data:application / x - oleobject; base64, C8E7L7ZFLUeFnCABl + fZxwAIAABqJQAAxRoAAA =='; 
        this.config.element.appendChild(objElement);

        var helper = CreateObject("Helper.WebHelper")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can declare the ActiveXObject (if it didn't exist), like this:

```
declare var ActiveXObject: (type: string) => void;
```

I mention this only because this is your standard way of getting stuff into the type system if it doesn't exist in the standard library.

However, `ActiveXObject` is already in the standard TypeScript library, so you don't need that - it will compile happily with:

```
var objElement = document.createElement('object');
objElement.classid = 'clsid:2F3BC10B-45B6-472D-859C-200197E7D9C7';
objElement.id = 'My Id';
objElement.data = 'data:application / x - oleobject; base64, C8E7L7ZFLUeFnCABl + fZxwAIAABqJQAAxRoAAA =='; 
this.config.element.appendChild(objElement);

var helper = new ActiveXObject("Helper.WebHelper");
```

As for your `object does not support this property or method` - once you have a handle on an ActiveX object, you are handcuffed to whatever that object supports.

Using the above code, `helper` holds your reference to the ActiveX object. Using `document.getElementById(...)` will give you back the element in the DOM (I presume an `object` element.) You need to use your `helper` variable to access the ActiveXObject.

Comment: getting undefined, i have tried ActiveXObject but getting Object doesn't support this action, how can i create ActiveX object?

Comment: The MSDN documentation suggests the syntax is `new ActiveXObject(servername.typename[, location])` so to get TypeScript to recognise this you'd need to write a declaration for this signature - bear in mind this is IE only, it will never work in another browser. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: thanks i forgot the new before the ActiveObject. also how come that when i am calling var helper var helper =document.getElementById('PlayerComponentX1'); helper.init i get exception and when doing it from the active object i get exception?

Comment: Is "init" a function? You need braces for that - init(). Otherwise, what error message do you get?

Comment: sure it is a function , sorry i didnt write the () though it is obevious, i am getting Object doesn't support property or method

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Fenton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19563740/111794), note that there are some ActiveX type definitions available on DefinitelyTyped ([Word](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/activex-word/index.d.ts), [Excel](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/activex-excel/index.d.ts), [LibreOffice](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/activex-libreoffice), [WIA](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/activex-wia/index.d.ts) and others). You can install these definitions like any others, e.g.:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/activex-excel
```

If these definitions don't help, I've written a [project](https://github.com/zspitz/ts-activex-gen) that generates Typescript definition files from ActiveX type libraries (either registered on the system, or from a file).